# Running selenium with Javascript on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am a noob to Javascript so apologies if my question is very trivial.

I am trying to run a selenium test that was wrote in Javascript. As I usually do, I just want to start with something simple and work from there. In my script I am just trying to load Google using chromedriver.

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

On the CLI I navigate to the directory where the `Test.js` file is saved in and I run the command `node Test.js`. I always get this error in response;

```
C:\Selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\_base.js:104
    vm.runInContext(opt_srcText, closure, src);
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at goog.loadModuleFromSource_ (C:\Selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\l
at Object.goog.loadModule (C:\Selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\g
at C:\Selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1:6
at Object.Context.closure.goog.retrieveAndExecModule_ (C:\Selenium\node_modu
at <anonymous>:1:6
at Context.closure.closure.vm.createContext.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT (C:\Seleni
at Object.goog.importScript_ (C:\Selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\li
at Object.goog.importModule_ (C:\Selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\li
at Object.goog.writeScripts_ (C:\Selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\li
at Object.goog.require (C:\Selenium\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog
```

I originally ran this code on my Windows machine and when I was getting that error I put it down to Windows and Node.js no agreeing and tried it on my Mac. Still no luck as I was getting the exact same response.

On both machines I have node and npm installed. Previous to executing the tests I ran the command `npm install selenium-webdriver` and I also added `chromedriver` to my PATH.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong so if anyone can point me in the right direction, it'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: I've copied your code into a file and ran it without any issues at all. I'm on Linux but I doubt that's what made the difference.

Comment: On my MAC, node version is 0.10.26 and npm version is 3.4.1. Don't know if the versions are out too old?

Comment: Node 0.10.26 may be too old. I run 4..2.2.

Comment: I updated node on my windows machine and it is running now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the version of node I was using was too old.
Thanks to @Louis for your help in reaching this solution.

What I did was uninstall node and re-installed it with the latest version. I would imagine upgrading would work too.

Comment: I had the problem at ubuntu. So the update was hard but using this url was useful: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server